# How to show categories without li tags in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, wp-list-categories

I need some help with the wordpress function Wp_list_categories()
I want to display the categories links  inside a tag `<div>` like this:

```
<div class="myclass">
  <a>a category</a>
</div>
```

If I use wp_list_categories() I get the category links wrapped in li tags which also show the bullet ◦ before each category.

i wonder if there's any method like this:

```
wp_get_archives('format=custom type=monthly &before=<div class="voices">&after=</div>');
```

that gives me:

```
<div class="voices">
  <a>something</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wp_get_post_categories(): https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_post_categories/

Example:

```
<?php
    $categories = wp_get_post_categories(get_the_ID());

    echo '<div class="voices">';
    foreach($categories as $category){
        echo '<a>' . get_cat_name($category) . '</a>';
    }
    echo '</div>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add `titie_li` & `style` attributes to `wp_list_categories`, like the following code:

```
wp_list_categories(array('title_li' => false, 'style' => false));
```

Comment: Could I use my own icon as the bullet using this method?